# Filtered data without using RLS

Tags: powerbi, row-level-security, data-security, filtered

In Power BI, have two tables: one for **UsersData** and one for **CountryData**.
The *Username* and *Country* columns can be identified in the **UsersData** table and the *Country* and *CityName* columns are in the **CountryData** table. The **CountryData** and **UsersData** tables are connected by using *Country*. Visualize the Country name and city in a table in the Power report view.

[image]

Requirement: When a user logs into the power bi service, he wants to see only the data related to the user. **I looking for any suggestions to implement this scenario without using RLS.**

Comment: Why RLS can't be used? It is the right tool, designed for this task.

Comment: RLS (Row level security) is commonly used to restrict data access for given users. However, in this case, I am only contemplating data filtering based on the user. 
So, in theory, is it appropriate to use the Power BI RLS option in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Without RLS you can write a measure based on the current user, eg

```
IsCurrentUser = if(USERPRINCIPALNAME() = SELECTEDVALUE(Users[User]),1,0)
```

and use that to filter a visual.

[image]

And the [Chiclet Slicer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380756) supports "Forced Selection" so if you filter the Chicklet Slicer down to a single item, it will be automatically selected.

The tables and relationships would be set up the same way you would for RLS, eg

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
That will be the solution to achieve my requirement. 

but I am looking for some approach to filter the data from the table level (I mean tables that include in Data view and Model view) without using RLS. 
As an example, I want to create a new table called **UserCities**, its data needs to be filtered by the user who logs into the power bi service.

Comment: I tried the following query, but it gives some errors.

UserCities = 
CALCULATETABLE(
DISTINCT(
    SELECTCOLUMNS('Countries', 
                "Country", 'Countries'[Country],
                "City", 'Countries'[CityName]
    ) 
    ), Users[UserName] = USERPRINCIPALNAME()
)